# Reactor Framework (Flux) - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Tags: project-reactor, flux, reactor

I am trying to get all cf applications using java reactor framework

```
Flux<ApplicationSummary> appFlux= _cloudFoundryOperations.applications().list();
List<ApplicationSummary> result = appFlux.collectList().block();
```

This call is being made every 5 minutes to get the applications deployed recently.

it works well for few couple of hours, later it returns "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError". The stack trace is below, How can I do this call efficiently?

```
"stacktrace": [
  "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory",
  "\tat java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:711)",
  "\tSuppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: \nAssembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap] :\n\treactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1877)\n\torg.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v2.organizations.ReactorOrganizations.list(ReactorOrganizations.java:202)\nError has been observed at the following site(s):\n\t|_ Mono.checkpoint ⇢ at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v2.organizations.ReactorOrganizations.list(ReactorOrganizations.java:202)\n\t|_ Flux.checkpoint ⇢ at org.cloudfoundry.operations.applications.DefaultApplications.list(DefaultApplications.java:330)\nStack trace:",
  "\t\tat java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:711)",
  "\t\tat java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)",
  "\t\tat java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.unix.Buffer.allocateDirectWithNativeOrder(Buffer.java:40)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventArray.<init>(EpollEventArray.java:56)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.<init>(EpollEventLoop.java:95)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:151)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:35)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:112)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:99)",
  "\t\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:76)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll.newEventLoopGroup(DefaultLoopEpoll.java:64)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopResources.cacheNativeServerLoops(DefaultLoopResources.java:252)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopResources.cacheNativeClientLoops(DefaultLoopResources.java:267)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopResources.onClient(DefaultLoopResources.java:199)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientRunOn.configure(TcpClientRunOn.java:51)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientRunOn.configure(TcpClientRunOn.java:43)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientSecure.configure(TcpClientSecure.java:53)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientDoOn.configure(TcpClientDoOn.java:48)",
  "\t\tat reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:196)",
  "\t\tat org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.DefaultSslCertificateTruster.getUntrustedCertificates(DefaultSslCertificateTruster.java:166)",
  "\t\tat org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.DefaultSslCertificateTruster.trust(DefaultSslCertificateTruster.java:91)",
  "\t\tat org.cloudfoundry.reactor._DefaultConnectionContext.lambda$trust$1(_DefaultConnectionContext.java:155)",
  "\t\tat java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)",
  "\t\tat org.cloudfoundry.reactor._DefaultConnectionContext.trust(_DefaultConnectionContext.java:155)",
  "\t\tat org.cloudfoundry.reactor.DefaultConnectionContext.trust(DefaultConnectionContext.java:23)",
  "\t\tat org.cloudfoundry.reactor.AbstractRootProvider.trust(AbstractRootProvider.java:136)",
  "\t\tat org.cloudfoundry.reactor.AbstractRootProvider.lambda$getRoot$3(AbstractRootProvider.java:70)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.subscribeNextTrigger(MonoDelayUntil.java:210)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.onNext(MonoDelayUntil.java:169)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2317)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2125)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:68)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4218)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:134)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1994)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:134)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:134)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:126)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:126)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:126)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1802)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:323)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onError(MonoCacheTime.java:346)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:126)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.onError(MonoDelayUntil.java:175)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.subscribeNextTrigger(MonoDelayUntil.java:213)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.onNext(MonoDelayUntil.java:169)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2317)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.onSubscribe(MonoDelayUntil.java:159)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:132)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:132)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8311)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:199)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:132)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:132)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4203)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4218)",
  "\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1677)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.cf.CfApi.getApplications(CfApi.java:124)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.cf.CfApi.getCloudFoundryMetrics(CfApi.java:92)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.cf.GetCloudFoundryMetricsCommand.getCloudFoundryMetrics(GetCloudFoundryMetricsCommand.java:35)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.services.healthdata.HealthServiceClient.readCloudFoundryMetrics(HealthServiceClient.java:170)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.services.healthdata.FetchHealthDataCommand.processLandscapeHealthData(FetchHealthDataCommand.java:51)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.services.healthdata.HealthFactsImporter.run(HealthFactsImporter.java:39)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.services.healthdata.HealthFactsImporterAsJob.lambda$run$0(HealthFactsImporterAsJob.java:46)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.cds.services.impl.runtime.CdsRuntimeImpl.runInRequestContext(CdsRuntimeImpl.java:154)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.services.healthdata.HealthFactsImporterAsJob.run(HealthFactsImporterAsJob.java:44)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.crun.healthapi.services.healthdata.HealthFactsImporterAsJob$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$211f9f83.invoke(<generated>)",
  "\t\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)",
  "\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)",
  "\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)",
  "\t\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)",
  "\t\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)",
  "\t\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)",
  "\t\tat com.sap.dwc.util.headers.DwcContextTaskDecorator.lambda$decorate$0(DwcContextTaskDecorator.java:33)",
  "\t\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)",
  "\t\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)",
  "\t\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)"
]
```

Could someone help here?

Comment: What are you doing with the collected application list? Do you need to hold all of them in memory?

Comment: i do not need to hold it in the memory. Once I receive the application list, I will persist in my own table. .

Answer (score 0):

```
Flux<ApplicationSummary> appFlux= _cloudFoundryOperations.applications().list();
List<ApplicationSummary> result = appFlux.collectList().block();
```

Without knowing more context directly, this looks like an awful lot like it will get a list of *all* applications. This is contrary to what you state you require:

> This call is being made every 5 minutes to get the **applications deployed recently.**

...and this is likely why you're also running out of memory, as the list likely simply gets way too big to fit in memory all at once. If you *genuinely* need this complete list every 5 minutes and it won't fit into memory, then there's nothing you can do - you either need to re-architect your application, or add more memory (though the latter is likely not a feasible option after a certain point!)

You don't go into detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but there's two options that may well fit your use case:

- Ideally, you wouldn't block at all - but if you just need 5 minutes worth of values processed as a list every 5 minutes, then you can simply window the flux in that timespan then do as you please with the result:

```
_cloudFoundryOperations.applications().list()
        .window(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
        .flatMap(Flux::collectList)
        .doOnNext(list -> {
            //process list
        })
```

- As the "least change" approach If you want to block each time as you're doing now, but want to make sure you don't run out of memory, you can use `takeLast()` with some kind of sensible value to get the last `n` elements (which will work if you're happy with the last `n` applications deployed):

```
_cloudFoundryOperations.applications().list()
        .takeLast(10_000)
        .collectList().block()
```

...however, remember that blocking generally defeats the purpose of using reactor (unless you're specifically doing it as part of an ongoing migration or because there's no other choice) - so my best advice would be to try to engineer all blocking calls out of your system entirely.

Comment: Hello Michael,

I will make use of the first approach. in this case, when I use window(), I hope to recive the  latest applications deployed in the last 5 minutes.

Besides this, I get the same problem for Mono block(),

response = _cloudFoundryOperations.getCloudFoundryClient().applicationsV2()
.statistics(request).block();

we do not have window() for mono. Any idea?

Comment: Any time you're getting an `OutOfMemoryError` in this context it's likely because the value you're trying to collect (or block) is too large. In a `Flux` it's easier to solve because you can just collect in smaller chunks, or individually - if there's a single `Mono` value causing that issue it's less clear, as there's not an inherently obvious way to split that up. You either "get" the `Mono` or you don't. The only thing I'd suggest is looking at the API to see if there's a better way to get statistics.